# Azure ServiceBus Eventhub, is the "offset" still available/durable when some of event data is expired?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

When I write some code to test the EventHub which is a newly released on azure service bus.

As there is very few article online and msdn also do not have rich documentation about the detail of event hub. So I hope someone could share your experience for my question.

For EventHub, we have following statement:

- we use "offset" to remember where we are when reading the event data from some partition
- the event data on the EventHub would be expired (automatically?) after some configurable time span

So my question is, can the `offset` still be available/durable when some of the event data is deleted as the result of expiration?

For example, we have following data on one of partition:

```
M1 | M2 | M3 | M4  ( oldest --> latest )
```

After my processing logic runs, let's say that I have processed `M1` and `M2`, so the offset would be the start of `M2`(when use exclusive mode).

After some time, and if my service is down during that time. `M1` is deleted as the result of expiration. so the partition would become:

```
M2 | M3 | M4 | M.... ( oldest -> latest )
```

In this case, when my server is restart again, is the offset i stored before is still be available to be used to read from `M3`?

We can also image this case on runtime when my consumer server is reading the event data on eventhub when some of the oldest event data is expired, does the `offset` still be available on runtime?

Thanks for any sharing of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon how various parts of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubreceiver.startingoffset.aspx) [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.sequencenumber.aspx) [written](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.offset.aspx) I believe you will start from the beginning of the current stream as desired if your [starting offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubreceiver.startingoffset.aspx) is no longer available. [EventProcessorHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessorhost.aspx) should follow similar restrictions. Since the [sequence numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.offset.aspx) are 64 bits, I would expect one of those to be able to serve as an offset within a partition since they monotonically increase without being recycled. The [offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.offset.aspx) should have a similar property. So if EventHubs are designed in a reasonable fashion (ie like similar solutions), then the offsets within partitions can hold despite data expiration. But since I have not yet tested this myself, I will be very unhappy if it is not so, and I'd expect an Azure person to be able to give true confirmation.

Comment: Yes, I have the same assumption and I hope the azure team have already been aware of that and make it implemented in the current released sdk.